# Most efficient way to modify a path with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a load of social buttons (`<img>`s in a `<ul>`) on the right-handle side of my site.

They might have filenames such as `google.png`, or `twitter.png`.

I now want to change the `src` on hover to `google_b.png` or `twitter_b.png` - and I will consistently be naming my files in this way for all of them.

My question is how can I easily change the filenames to and from the `_b` (maintaining the file extension) without having to predifine the filenames?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
$('#social li').hover(function() {
    // hover in
    // a bunch of code to animate a tooltip is here

    var $img = $t.children('img'),
        src = $img.attr('src');
    // change the source to img_b.png
    $img.attr('src', src);
}, 
function() {
    // hover out

    var $img = $(this).children('img'),
        src = $img.attr('src');
    // remove _b to make it img.png again
    $img.attr('src', src);
});
```

Comment: Most efficient way is probably to use classes for the images and just swap the classes when you hover. But you said you don't want to predefine the image names so I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: Can't you just change the strings with a regex or something? Efficiency (in terms of performance) isn't really a consideration here, as you're just manipulating one element in the event loop. It'd be hard to find a way to do it that's so terrible as to cause a real problem, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy yeah I could but I'm awful at regex :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#social li').hover(function() {
    // hover in
    // a bunch of code to animate a tooltip is here

    var $img = $t.children('img'),
        src = $img.attr('src').replace(".png", "_b.png");
    // change the source to img_b.png
    $img.attr('src', src);
}, 
function() {
    // hover out

    var $img = $(this).children('img'),
        src = $img.attr('src').replace("_b.png", ".png");
    // remove _b to make it img.png again
    $img.attr('src', src);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming files won't have fake extensions (`image.png.jpeg`) just split the src on `.`, add `_b` to second to last part and join again on `.`.

```
src = $img.attr('src');
var temp = src.split(".");
temp[temp.length - 2] += "_b"; //change second to last element of array
src = temp.join(".");
```

Comment: nice, but why wouldn't you just use `temp[0] += "_b"`?

Comment: Since there's no guarantee that the `src` will split into exactly 2 parts. It may contain the full domain name, which will contain multiple `.`s

Answer (score 0):

You could use the data function in jQuery to store the info so you won't have to constantly recalculate it.

```
$('#social li img').each(function(){
    var image = this.src.split(".");
    var onImage = image[0] + "_b." + image[1];

    $(this).data("onImage",onImage);
    $(this).data("offImage",this.src);

}).hover(function(){
    this.src = $(this).data("onImage");
},function(){
    this.src = $(this).data("offImage");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could extract the src attribute directly from each image using the jquery attr() function, append characters to it like '_b' and is it on hover.

Comment: I said "preserving the file extension" in the question

Comment: I din't mean, 'lets just go crazy and remove the file extension'. I meant simply parsing the src attribute, extracting the file-name, appending characters to it, and setting it on hover, a solution given in greater detail by everybody else on this page :)